# Acumatica REST API Exception Messages

Tags: c#, winforms, postman, acumatica

I am developing a Windows Forms application using the Acumatica REST API. I am working on error handling and would like to present the user with meaningful error messages. I notice that when I test with PostMan I can inner exceptions with error messages.

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Opportunity.ClassID: 'Class ID' cannot be found in the system.\nInserting  'Opportunity' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.",
  "exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OutcomeEntityHasErrorsException",
  "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetOperationResult(EntityImpl entity, 

  ...
  ...
}
```

However, when I use HttpClient in C#, I get only basic 500 errors. The inner exceptions are null.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

My put code looks like this:

```
 public string Put(string entityName, string parameters, string entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = _httpClient.PutAsync(
                 _acumaticaAPI + entityName + "?" + parameters,
                new StringContent(entity, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"API PUT Error: {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

How can I get proper detail from exceptions in my forms application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I'm using.

Notice that after the call to `client.PutAsync()`, I am not using the `.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` syntax.

I am using `var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, stringContent);`

Afterwards, I check the response code and if it's not successful, I continue to get the response in order to get the error message via `err = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`.

I'm using NewtownSoft and deserializing the error response into a class I call `ResponseMessage`.

```
        public async Task<T> PutData<T>(T data, string entity)
        {
            err = "";
            msg = new ResponseMessage();

            T respData = default(T);

            if (await Login() == false) return respData;

            var uri = new Uri(settings.url + settings.endpoint + entity); 
            try
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, stringContent);
                
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    
                    respData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
                }
                else
                {
                    err = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    

                    try
                    {
                        msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseMessage>(err);
                        if (msg != null) err = msg.exceptionMessage == "" ? msg.message : msg.exceptionMessage;
                        return respData;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        err = ex.Message;
                        msg.exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
                        return respData;
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                err = ex.Message;
                return respData;
            }

            return respData;
        }
```

It deserializes the response into the following class

```
    public class ResponseMessage
    {
        public string exceptionMessage { get; set; } = "";
        public string message { get; set; } = "";
    }
```